# FAQ: What makes a good post?

Tags: discussion, faq, community-guidelines

Lets have some examples of what goes into a good post. Both question and answer here. This will become the community standard that we can point users to in the future when we have low quality entries or posts that need a bit of work.

Comment: Can we add a question mark in the title? I can't edit your post. I suffer from OCD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Example Question:

---

**Title:** How can I publish an item programatically?

---

**Body:**

I have a custom import job that takes data from a CSV file and imports them into an Item Bucket.

When the job ends, I need to publish all the items that have been created.

#### What I have so far:

Here is the code that I use to import:

```cs
public class CsvImport() 
{
    public void Process(string csvPath)
    {
        var data = ReadCsvFile(csvPath);
        var importedItems = new List<Item>();

        foreach(var row in data)
        {
            var newItem = ImportRow(row);
        }

        // TODO: Publish those items that are imported:
    }

    private List<IRow> ReadCsvFile(string csvPath)
    {
        //....
    }

    private List<Item> ImportItem(IRow row)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

What is the best option here? Should I use `PublishManager` or another method?

---

### What Makes This Good?

- The title contains a simple to the point question
- The body adds detail to the question in the title
- There is an example of what the OP has tried
- Code examples have syntax highlighting enabled ([How to add Syntax Highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work#answer-184109))
- Class names, variables etc... in the body of the text have been marked as a `Code Block`
- There are headings for important things

Comment: Good basis, what would I do if I had a screen shot or an image? 
What about if I have a link that leads to an answer? Do I expand upon the context of the link?

Sorry just throwing thoughts out there, you've started a base wondering if we can add to it rather then me creating a new answer.

Comment: @Anicho This is an example of a *question*, like Habitat you should not use it in production, it is only guidelines. We should add more types of questions and answers examples.

Comment: @jammykam oops good shout, I was in the cloud there!

Comment: It would be great if we could remind everyone to maybe put their version of Sitecore/Sitecore Commerce/Module/What have you near the top of the question. Helps frame context for the rest of the question!

Answer (score 7):

I'm a fan of the best practices tag/style questions, but they're difficult to frame and can quickly get away from objective to subjective. That said, some do's/don'ts for best practices items (Mods, please edit and revise as appropriate)

- **Don't** ask for general opinions about a product, feature or facet. ie -- "Is TDS any good?".
- **Do** give specific details around why you're considering a certain feature. ie -- "I have a project trying to accomplish ____ while following Helix practices. How should I structure this feature?"
- **Do** ask for opinions on this or that comparisons, but only if you've given enough context to have the community help steer you in an objective direction. ie -- "What build system should I use if I want to build non-Sitecore projects along side my Sitecore projects?"
- **Do** describe any due diligence you've already done, why something you already tried didn't work, and the like.

There are probably more things we can all think of to help shape these kinds of questions to be more helpful! These are the ones that I had on the top of mind.

Comment: Nothing worse than badly worded, open-ended questions with vague requirements. Knowing how to ask a good question is very important.

Answer (score 5):

## Use of images

Think carefully about how much your image really improves the question / answer.

Images should be cropped to just show as much information as required. Full-browser screenshots should not be necessary unless it's important to the issue at hand.

If the image is being used to show an error *message*, then **the body of the question should still include the error text itself**. This not only makes it more readable, it will greatly improve the searchability of the question and help other users to find it.

Images of generic errors, such as the ASP.NET Yellow Screen Of Death, should **not** be included as the image offers no information that couldn't be conveyed by text.

Answer (score 3):

Since the beta, we have been trying to keep the questions and answers cleanly formatted. This includes the syntax highlighting. It is crucial that we all make an effort to keep this going.

One of the things people with questions should do is to up vote appropriate answers and definitely come back and mark the answer on the question even if they found the solution.